# jQuery drop down list

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

new to javascript / jQuery. I have some data presented in an ordered list as follows

```
<ul>        
   <li data-id="">
    <a data-link="0" data-actiontype="article" href="#">Data 0</a>
   </li>
   <li data-id="">
    <a data-link="1" data-actiontype="article" href="#">Data 1.</a>
    </li>

    <li data-id="">
    <a data-link="2" data-actiontype="article" href="#">Data 2</a>
    </li>   
 <ul>
```

I would like to present the above in a drop down list rather on an ordered list please?

Comment: What info did your Google search provide?

Comment: Do you want to keep the same HTML? Why not just use <select>?

Comment: At the moment each list has a link that redirects to. When I use select and option in place of the ordered lists and I select one doesn't redirect to the link.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
<select>

<option> Data 0 </option>
.
.
.
<option> Data 2 </option>
</select>
```

To achieve this conversion with JQuery, you need to do something like this:

Have an empty select tag on the page

```
<select id="randomid"></select>
```

then add this to your script:

```
$('ul>li').each(function(i)
{
 $('#randomid').append($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Not sure this is working. What I need is my ordered lists to transformed to select options in a drop down list and when a user select one they will behave exactly as they do now which they redirect to the attached anchor link attached to them.

Answer (score 1):

By drop down list do you mean within one select box or as in hovering over a list item causes the list to appear?

if its the first, just a select tag can be used, with each list item set as an option.

if its the second method, you can give each of the elements a class and set that class to appear only when

Comment: The ul lists are returned from API. Instead of the lists I want a drop down select box with those options. I still need the anchor link to work when a user select an option